# Mule 3 Import | The selected folder does not contain a valid Studio project (missing mule-project.xml file)

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

As the error indicates, when I am trying to import a Mule project, I am getting error saying "Missing mule-project.xml" but the source I received does not contain it. Is there any workaround for this please?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new project in the development environment, copy the mule-project.xml file from that to your old project and then, if needed, make manual modifications to the mule-project.xml in the old project?

Comment: ok, yes, this worked. I followed the steps you told @IvanKrizsan. It shows some warnings now about updating project.xml file, but I am able to at least import and proceed. Thank you

Comment: @IvanKrizsan, can you please post this as answer so that i can mark it as answer? It might help newbie like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to create a new project in the development environment, copy the mule-project.xml file from that to your old project and then, if needed, make manual modifications to the mule-project.xml in the old project?

Answer (score 0):

The doppelganger for this in Mule 4 is the `Missing pom.xml`.

Same solution suggested by Ivan can be followed in Mule 4 as well.

Just to add more value for this question to help newbies.

> Never import an previously exported jar unless it's a mule deployable archive. The pom.xml  file needs to be present on the top level of the directory.

If your pom.xml is not present in the root upper most level of the  directory, then there is a possible folder manipulation occurred.

To make sure you indeed are using the correct code.

```
Always check your project structure.
```

Jar archives tends to manipulate your folder structure as per its needs to properly execute ; Just making them useful for deployments but useless for code rework.